# Angularfire5 - Get the key of Realtime database documents in list - #askfirebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire5

I am loading a list and passing it to a component to then render the information. One of the items I need is the ID. How can I see that in the list. I've seen the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/version-5-upgrade.md) and it does not help. It only shows the key of the parent.

```
this.allWorkouts = this.afDb.list<IWorkout>('/workouts')
    .valueChanges()
    .take(1)
    .map((array) => array.reverse()) as Observable<IWorkout[]>;
```

---

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let workout of allWorkouts | async">
    <card-workout [workout]="workout"></card-workout>
</ion-card>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 5.0 of AngularFire you need to [use `snapshotChanges()` if you want to get access to the key](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/rtdb/lists.md#snapshotchanges).

`valueChanges()` is only for basic use cases were you only care about the JSON tree.

Comment: with snapshotChanges, how do I get the document data?

Answer (score 0):

To get the key you need suscribe the observable and then print of this way:

```
suscribe(snapshot => { snapshot.$key })
```

If you need print into a *ngFor you should use:

```
workout.$key
```