# how can I get name of document inside collection with firestorage firebase?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

```
this.afs.collection<User>(`users`).valueChanges()
    .map(domains => {
        return this.convertToArray(domains).filter(domain => {
          return domain;
        });
    });
```

Domain returns:

```
{creationDate:1516798886902
displayName:"mohamedabo8414"
domain:"@mohamedabo8414"
followersCount:0
followingCount:0}
```

I want to get uid for this user. How can I do it?

Comment: Where is the uid?

Comment: I named domain object with uid like this
"VEtdoqabg4bkanB6Ky9CI3dvzOu1": {
creationDate:1516798886902
displayName:"mohamedabo8414"
domain:"@mohamedabo8414"
followersCount:0
followingCount:0}

Comment: [Related post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46742770/5861618) (although it uses the realtime database and not Firestore)

Answer (score 2):

`.valueChanges()` doesn't emit the keys with it. use `.snapshotChanges()` instead. Try

```
this.afs.collection<User>(`users`).snapshotChanges().map(actions=>{
    return actions.map(b=>{
      const data = b.payload.doc.data();
      const id = b.payload.doc.id;
      return {uid:id,...data}
    })
}).map(domains => {
    return this.convertToArray(domains).filter(domain => {
      return domain;
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks, I found the solution here 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=-GjF9pSeFTs

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment

> I named domain object with uid like this "VEtdoqabg4bkanB6Ky9CI3dvzOu1": { creationDate:1516798886902 displayName:"mohamedabo8414" domain:"@mohamedabo8414" followersCount:0 followingCount:0}

If you want to fetch the uid `VEtdoqabg4bkanB6Ky9CI3dvzOu1` then according to the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#~id), in your case `domain.id()` should get you the above uid.